# how to put sizer in the wx.SashLayoutWindow

Tags: wxpython

I'd like to put a sizer in the wx.SashLayoutWindow. So i can put some widgets in the sizer. Here is my code. 
t1 and t4 should arrange horizontal, but it appears vertical and they doesn't fit the bottomwin. 
Can anybody tell me the right way to put a sizer in the wx.SashLayoutWindow? thanks a lot!

```py
    bottomwin = wx.SashLayoutWindow(self, -1, wx.DefaultPosition, (200, 30), wx.NO_BORDER|wx.SW_3D)
    bottomwin.SetDefaultSize((-1, 45))
    bottomwin.SetOrientation(wx.LAYOUT_HORIZONTAL)
    bottomwin.SetAlignment(wx.LAYOUT_BOTTOM)
    bottomwin.SetBackgroundColour("#808080")
    bottomwin.SetSashVisible(wx.SASH_TOP, True)
    t4 = wx.TextCtrl(bottomwin, -1, "", size=(100, 10), style=wx.TE_MULTILINE | wx.TE_RICH2)
    t1 = wx.Button(bottomwin, -1, "Default Button", size=(80, -1))
    sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
    sizer.Add(t1, proportion=1, border=0, flag=wx.ALL | wx.EXPAND)
    sizer.Add(t4, proportion=1, border=0, flag=wx.ALL | wx.EXPAND)
    sizer.Fit(bottomwin)
    self.SetSizer(sizer)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally you would want to do:

```
botomwin.SetSizer(sizer)
```

instead of using `self`.  The sizer should be attached to the window (either directly or as a sub-sizer of one that is) that is the parent of the widgets that you want to manage the layout and size of with that sizer.

However, in this case, since `wx.SashLayoutWindow` derives from `wx.Window` it will not use the sizer by default. It actually has some custom code for managing the size and position of the child windows in accordance with the sash behavior.  So you will want to put something between the widgets and the `wx.SashLayoutWindow`. In other words, make a `wx.Panel` that is the child of `bottomwin`, put the widgets on the panel by specifying it as the parent, and assign the sizer to that panel.